# How to increment value of object property using javascript?

Tags: javascript

i have a object named output like below

```
const output = { 
    count {
        books: 3,
        pens: 2,
        name: 'first',
    }
}
```

i want to increment the books value by 1, name value to 'second' and leave pens value to be same.

what i have tried?

```
const books = output.count.books + 1;
const pens = output.count.pens;
const name = 'second';

output = {
    books: books,
    pens: pens,
    name: name,
}
```

How can i rewrite this code? could soemone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: If you want to change the values of the properties, just do `output.count.books += 1;` and `output.count.name = 'second';`.

Comment: Your first structure is a syntax error (there's no `:` after `count`), and your second structure doesn't match your first structure (there's no `count` property).  What happens when you correct the error and match the structure?

Comment: @HarshaHR There is no JSON. This is JavaScript.

Comment: @HarshaHR How is a data exchange format related to the question ..? OP clearly has a JS object initializer, which in the post seems to have a typo.

Comment: @HarshaHR JSON is data format. Despite the name, it is language independent. A JavaScript object is not JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just increment the values of books and update the name:

```js
const output = { 
    count: {books:3,pens:2,name:'first'}
}

output.count.books++;
output.count.name = 'second';
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed '**:**' in your object after 'count' and also you tried to override 'output' which is a constant.

```js
const output = { 
    count: {books:3,pens:2,name:'first'}
}

const books = output.count.books + 1;
const pens = output.count.pens;
const name = 'second';

let result = {
    books: books,
    pens: pens,
    name: name,
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```js
let output = { 
    count: {
        books: 3,
        pens: 2,
        name: 'first',
    }
}


const books = output.count.books + 1;
const pens = output.count.pens;
let name = output.count.name;
    name = "second";


output = {
    'books': books,
    'pens': pens,
    'name': name,
}

console.log(output);
```